# RxJs : Weird behavior with takeUntil?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Nothing too much serious here, just curious.
I wanted to make an example for something and came up with this code :

```
const { Observable, Subject } = Rx

const timeout$ = new Subject()

const obs$ = Observable
  .of(1)
  .takeUntil(timeout$)
  .delay(2000)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))

timeout$.next()
timeout$.complete()
```

I thought this code would **not** display the `console.log` but it does.

Can someone explain me why ?
Is this a bug or just a bad understanding from me about `takeUntil` ?

Here's a Plunkr to demo https://plnkr.co/edit/wpKztBabnBeIuNZS28wu?p=info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that if you switch the order of the `takeUntil()` and `delay()` it won't be emitted as expected:

```
Observable
  .of(1)
  .delay(2000)
  .takeUntil(timeout$)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

What you see happens because the `delay()` schedules the emission before that `takeUntil()` sends `complete` notification.
Right now in RxJS 5.2.0 the `takeUntil()` operator doesn't force unsubscribe from its source which is the problem here. So when the `takeUntil()` is notified by `timeout$` it remains subscribed to its source Observable and therefore the scheduled emission from `delay()` isn't disposed.

Notice there's no `this.unsubscribe()` call when handling emission from the notification Observable: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/takeUntil.ts#L61

There're other operators with the same behavior. For example `first()` and `takeWhile()`.

On the other hand for example the `take()` operator does unsubscribe:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/take.ts#L80

This behavior is in fact reported and whether this is a bug or not is being discussed right now:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2455
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2470
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2463
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2457

Comment: Thank you for that excellent answer :) ! Example, how to fix, references ... This is great ! Thanks !